# Woocommerce Amazon Pay how to set State Sales Tax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, amazon-pay

In Woocommerce I am using [WooCommerce Amazon Payments Advanced Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-paylabs-amazonpay/) plugin. Everything is working properly. But I want to add sales tax for particular state. In woocommerce Tax settings everything has been set. If user select different payment option and if their shipping state is "Connecticut" then tax is adding properly. But if user select Amazon pay option and their shipping state is "Connecticut" then Tax is not added. So can anyone please help me how can I set state tax for Amazon pay.

Comment: You are using plugin then please add name in specification

Comment: Yes I am using plugin. Plugin name is - WooCommerce Amazon Payments Advanced Gateway

Comment: You have your settings set to calculate tax based on customer’s shipping address. If the customer is not logged in, or does not yet have a saved shipping address, then taxes are not able to be calculated if there are no rates that match.

If you go to WooCommerce > Settings > General, what do you have set as the default customer address? If you set it to the Shop base address, and make sure that the shop base address has a matching address to a tax rule, then they should get tax included in the prices.

Comment: @Soumyadip Is that link of the plugin is correct?

Comment: Default customer address is set shop base address. On the Tax tab > Tax option I have now set Calculate Tax Based On: Customer shipping address. Now I have checked that on Amazon Pay tax calculated on shipping price but I want to tax calculated (Cart Subtotal+Shipping Price).

Comment: @Mujeebu this is the plugin link - https://woocommerce.com/products/pay-with-amazon/

Comment: Hello Vasim, Actually I want to set tax on Customer Subtotal for Amazon Pay. So can you please advise me how can I set this settings that when customer choose Amazon pay and if customer shipping address is "Connecticut" then add tax on subtotal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Amazon Pay WooCommerce payment gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-paylabs-amazonpay/) for your business
Install and active this plugin for your wordpress site

**Amazon Pay WooCommerce payment gateway features and benefits:**

- Single, Subscription and Recurring Payments
- Refund with Amazon Pay option from WP Admin
- Add WooCommerce Subscription Products
- Revenue with automatic Recurring Payment
- Customized Order status "Subscription & Recurring"
- Customized "Thank you page" message
- Mode of transaction Sandbox and Live
- Amazon Pay Transaction ID
- Seller Order Reference ID
- Next payment date for Recurring Payment
- LIVE Payment Status On "Thank you page"
- Alert/Notice for subscription product purchase on checkout page

Thanks.